# Viewing overlapping tuples in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am dealing with events that have a start time and a duration. Is it possible to see how many of these events are active at each timestamp (in Tableau)?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible via calculated fields if a data source with desired reference timestamps is blended in Tableau with your events data. In other words, you can create a table with times in Excel and use it as a frame to calculate how many events were active at time.
Is that what you had in mind?